# Exception number needed instead of message string

Tags: .net, exception, error-handling

I want to know if the exception is a "memoryoverflow exception" for example. But if the language on the Operating system is not English but Chinese for example or German, the message changes. And I cannot look the the message string anymore. On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.exception.aspx) I have not found a exception number to work with. How to find a exception number?

```
   Public Shared Sub Main()
      Dim x As Integer = 0
      Try
         Dim y As Integer = 100 / x
      Catch e As Exception'here, 123 is not working
         if e is ArithmeticException(123) then Console.WriteLine("Generic Exception Handler: {0}", e.ToString())
      End Try
   End Sub
```

[image: Error handling]

**Example** (look at the <-- line)

```
   Try
                    m_DxFilGraphManager.Run()
                Catch ex As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
                    If ex.Message.Contains("0x800705AA") Then '<-- Bad methode. How to do it better?
                        Return "#ERROR: Can not start capturing. It seems to be a possiblity to change the IEEE 1394 bus host controler system driver in your device manager to 'legacy / alt'. " & ex.Message
                    Else
                        Return "#ERROR: " & ex.Message
                    End If
      End Try
```

Comment: `ErrorCode` is not a general member of `System.Exception`. Some specific exception types provide such members (also consider the various information on `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`), but in general you first catch by type and then (if necessary) see if there is more information available using exception (type) specific information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally in .NET (although that is not enforced by anything but convention), there is a dedicated Exception-type derived from `System.Exception` for each cause. So, for example, your "memory overflow" would most likely be signaled by `System.OutOfMemoryException`. Checkout [the System.Exception class hierarchy on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.systemexception%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for more information about the exception types in the .NET framework. Although your code and 3rd party components can always define their own.

Having that said, their are certainly hairy cases, like for example with `IOException`. Sometimes you almost don't get around trying to parse error messages - which may be localized of course. Most of the times you can get around this issues.

As a rule, make sure you catch only the exception type you are actually interested in. Also, you may want to limit to number of statements in your try-block to be (rather) sure you are reacting on an exception raised by correct statement.

Finally, too coarse grained exception handling is equally bad as too fine grained exception handling. It always depends on your actual code.

Comment: @Christian.K: I've added an image. I cannot fully believe that you will now parse the message to catch the exception in the image. Or I missunderstood?

Comment: @Nasenbaer: No, you don't parse the message. You catch the specific exception type that as being thrown. If you are faced with an API that doesn't throw exception types specific enough (for your purposes), you have to sometimes resort to other means, including, but not limited to looking at the message text. But really, that should be the exception (no pun intended).

Comment: @Christian.K: Sorry. I don't understand. Perhaps because of my bad English? I now included some code. Can you please try again to tell me how you would catch the specified exception with the message content "Systemressourcen" without using the message string?

Comment: @Nasenbaer: I got confused because originally you where talking about an `ArithmeticException`, which is pretty specific I think, but of course YMMV, but now it is a `COMException`, which is rather generic by itself. I would ask myself whether you *really* need to know the specific reason. At least in your example (and oftentimes in reality as well) you don't really need to know as your error handling will most likely be equal.

Comment: @Nasenbaer: I think you *can* test the `ErrorCode` property of the [`COMException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comexception%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for equality to your error code. If that is a stable value or meaningful at all, is of course dependent on the external code that raised the exception.

Comment: @Christian.K: I cannot test here. This will change my mind completly but would be great! Are you sure it is allowed to work with `ErrorCode` on all computers (different OS' and hardware but same exception message)?

Comment: @Nasenbaer: No I'm not sure, however, I would *expect* that it is safe to do that. At least the MSDN pages don't suggest that it is not allowed to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Use proper exception handling:

```
Public Shared Sub Main()
  Dim x As Integer = 0
  Try
     Dim y As Integer = 100 / x
  Catch e As ArithmeticException
     // handle ArithmeticException
  Catch e As Exception
     // handle Exception
  End Try
End Sub
```

Catching `Exception` is bad practice - I suggest reading [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229005.aspx).

There are several specific exception types you can use - [`DivideByZeroException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dividebyzeroexception.aspx), [`NotFiniteNumberException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notfinitenumberexception.aspx) derive from [`ArithmeticException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.arithmeticexception.aspx).

Comment: I added an image. ArithmeticException is not precise enought. And as far as I tested, the **ErrorCode** property does not return consistent values, does it?

Comment: @Nasenbaer - As far as I know the HResult is determined at runtime when the exception is created/thrown. It will not be consistent on the same machine.

Comment: thats what I mean. But I need a consistent methode instead of a local way to solve or handle the exception. ArithmeticException is not a single exception but contains a huge list of possibilities. I only want to select one single exception to process. How to?